# Медиа-запросы CSS не работают. Что я делаю не так?

Tags: css

Столкнулась с проблемой:
один из стилей CSS, используемый мною в дизайне сайта, сильно тормозит работу сайта с мобильника (тестирую на айфоне). Поэтому решила его не использовать для мобильных. Прописываю медиазапрос `@media screen and (max-width: 990px)`, но он не работает, когда я просматриваю страницу с телефона и по-прежнему тормозит работу сайта (часто даже телефон полностью зависает).

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему! Ниже код; первый сам стиль:

```
.blur-gallery {
  list-style:none;
  margin: 50px auto; padding: 0;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 0;
}

.blur-gallery li {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
  width: 30%; min-width: 250px; height: auto;
  margin: 2px;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.blur-gallery:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px) grayscale(1);
  opacity: .7;
}
```

на втором медиазапрос:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 990px) {
 .blur-gallery {
  list-style:none;
  margin: 50px auto; padding: 0;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 0;
 }

 .blur-gallery li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%; min-width: 250px; height: auto;
  margin: 2px;
 }

 .blur-gallery:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%; min-width: 250px; height: auto;
  margin: 2px;
 }
}
```

Comment: А с чего вы взяли что CSS виновник зависания сайта? не думаю что стили способны быть причастны к зависанию сайта, тем более с iphone ))

Comment: потому что когда просматриваю конкретно этот блок - телефон зависает. А в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Думаю проблема в другом...., если возможно дайте ссылку для проверки

Comment: unitalia.ru блок с фотографиями

Comment: я никаких зависаний не заметил на мобильнике, думаю проблема с вашим браузером, попробуйте удалить все кеши из браузера и снова проверить или же проверьте другим браузером.

Comment: очистка кэша не помогает. Браузер Safari. Другой установить не могу на телефон (требует последней версии iOS, а на iPhone 4 она не обновляется). Ни на каких других сайтах так не зависает.((
И все же почему не срабатывает медиазапрос? Хотелось бы разобраться

Comment: Ну, во первых, зачем скрины, если можно скопировать-вставить код? Так на него и смотреть приятнее, и поисковики его проиндексируют. Второе: `десктоп хром` /`iphone5 safari` полет нормальный, медиазапросы пашут, во всяком случае, блок картинок представился колонкой. Лагов никаких тоже нет. На старте, десктоп однако, провалился в зависание, но я грешу на рабочий комп, который по совместительству местный сервак `=\ `

Comment: Прошу прощения, не знала, что можно код вставить(( я здесь тоько зарегистрировалась.
Блок картинок с самого начала выстравался колонкой, без медиазапроса.

Comment: Зависание происходит когда нажимаю на картинку

Comment: Я нажал на картинку, изменений нет, просто криво блоки стоят и всё.. )

Comment: блоки-то криво - это не проблема - выровняю. Пока зависла над проблемой с медиазапросами. В любом случае, спасибо за участие))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш медиа-запрос на мобильном разрешении (320 пикселей по ширине для айфона) будет дублировать основной код, ничего к нему не добавляя.

Если вы хотите разнести имеющийся код так, чтобы совсем не надо было ничего перекрывать, то пропишите медиа-запросы таким образом:

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
  // ваш код для экранов 320 пикселей и меньше
}

@media (min-width: 321px) {
  // ваш код для экранов 321 пиксель и больше
}
```

Comment: Большущее спасибиеще!! Вроде помогло!!